# Multiple applications sharing code offline

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, reference, shared-libraries

I am developing two windows desktop applications, one with a GUI and one without. (In visual studio 2013, c#) These applications are using very similar code and would like to know if and how they can share it.

I've looked at project references but feel like the client would have to specify search paths for a shared class library in order to have the applications find the shared code when installed. The applications will run offline.

Clarification;
Application A & B share code. When installing both applications (offline), these need to share code without the user having to bother with linking to a shared-code-project. This project or class library would need to somehow be installed together with an application.

Easiest solution I can think of is simply duplicating the code which I'm obviously trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to accomplish what you want:

1) Create a third project where you put all your shared code. Then reference this new project in both your apps. Sure, you'll ship that assembly twice but the code itself won't have to be duplicated.

2) Register your shared assembly in the GAC. This way, you'll only ship the assembly once and both your apps will use the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your shared code in a Class Library project. In Project A and Project B reference the Class Library project for common functionality

When creating the installer the projects would have the referenced Class Library within the package and will be deployed with your respective applications

Answer (score 0):

Create the library and deploy it with both type of application